# Como recupero um resultado de dentro da "onActivityResult" na minha activity

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando usar a camera do celular como leitor de codigo de barras.

Eu consigo recuperar o codigo de barras, e ver o resultado dentro do "onActivityResult", porem, eu preciso levar o resultado que obtive, para a minha função principal, e nao estou conseguindo.

Segue o codigo abaixo.

Função principal:

```
public void clickProducts(){


    listProdutos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            showCamera();
```

Função showCamera:

```
private void showCamera() {
    try {
        //start the scanning activity from the com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);



    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        //on catch, show the download dialog
        showDialog(ProductsListToThatSchoolAndUser.this, "Nenhuma câmera habilitada.", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Sim", "Não").show();
    }
}
```

onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //get the extras that are returned from the intent
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

            Toast.makeText(ProductsListToThatSchoolAndUser.this, contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }
}
```

Eu gostaria de usar o resultado de "contents", dentro da minha função "clickProducts()", mas não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 1):

> Eu gostaria de usar o resultado de "contents", dentro da minha função "clickProducts()", mas não estou conseguindo.

Não conseguirá.

Quando o botão for clicado já o método `clickProducts()` terá terminado.
Por outro lado, a obtenção do resultado é feito de forma assíncrona. Após `showCamera()` ser chamado o método `onItemClick()`termina.

Terá de colocar o código que vai lidar com o resultado no método `onActivityResult()` ou, melhor ainda, criar um método próprio e chamá-lo no `onActivityResult()`.

```
private void handleScanResult(String contents){
    //Faça aqui o que quer com `contents`
    Toast.makeText(ProductsListToThatSchoolAndUser.this, contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //get the extras that are returned from the intent
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            handleScanResult(contents);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: entendi. Tentei setar o content em um EditText que tenho dentro dessa pagina e nao deu certo. Estou começando agora a programação android, muitas coisas ainda sao novas pra mim.

Comment: private void handleScanResult(String contents){
        //Faça aqui o que quer com `contents`
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_product ,null);
        final EditText cbarrasLeitor = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cbarrascheck);

        cbarrasLeitor.setText(contents);
    }

Comment: Bruno, isso é outro problema e deve ser tratado noutra pergunta. Veja como o site funciona na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e em [Como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).